# Changes in Model .NET asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i've created a project using this steps

Create Model;
Create Controller from Model and scaffolding Views;

I've tried to access, and it works fine, but I've made some changes in Model rebuilt and tried to run one more time, and now i got this error:

> {"The model backing the 'CodingContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."}

This error brings a null inner exception

and this is the stack:

> at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Coding.Controllers.CorController.Index() in c:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Coding\Coding\Controllers\CorController.cs:line 19
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass37.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49()

I think the problem is about refresing the database using this new Model, but i can't found any command that solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer, and then accept it (it will be a couple of days before you can actually accept it, but wait and then do it). That way it's easier for future users to quickly find the solution to the problem =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Someone got the same problem, I got this answer with some friend help, you must to follow these steps to update your database:

Open The package manager console: Tools –> Library Package Manager –> Package Manager Console

Install Entity Framework: **Install-Package EntityFramework**

Run: **Enable-Migrations**

At this point I'd got problems, but the Visual Studio show me the answer, is just a problem of multiple Contexts

Run: **Add-Migration**

Then: **Update-Database**

And it's done, every change in you model, require to run these commands!